# TS2339: Property 'users' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

Im switching from JS to TS while learning React. Im facing this problem now.

The initial state for my context is empty and it cannot find the properties.

Here the repo if you prefer
https://github.com/lets-c-whats/ts-github-finder/blob/main/src/components/users/UserResults.tsx

context file

```
const GithubContext = createContext({});

interface GithubContextProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export const GithubProvider = ({ children }: GithubContextProps) => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  const fetchUsers = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`${GITHUB_URL}/users`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `token ${GITHUB_TOKEN}`,
      },
    });

    const data = await response.json();

    setUsers(data);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <GithubContext.Provider
      value={{
        users,
        loading,
        fetchUsers
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </GithubContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default GithubContext;
```

Im wraping the App with the provider and within Home component is the component UserResults

```
import { GithubProvider } from "./context/github/githubContext";
...
function App() {
  return (
    <GithubProvider>
      ...
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    </GithubProvider>
  );
}
```

After that Im requesting the values inside the component using the useContext hook

```
// DEPENDENCIES
import { useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import GithubContext from "../../context/github/githubContext";



function UserResults() {
  const {users, loading, fetchUsers} = useContext(GithubContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers()
  })

  if (!loading) {
    return (
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-8 xl:grid-cols-4 lg:grid-cols-3 md:grid-cols-2">
        {users.map((user) => {
          return <UserItem key={user.id} userData={user} />;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return <Spinner />
  }
}
export default UserResults;
```

after all that the app does not work it throws these errors:

```
TS2339: Property 'users' does not exist on type '{}'.
     8 |
     9 | function UserResults() {
  > 10 |   const {users, loading, fetchUsers} = useContext(GithubContext)
       |          ^^^^^
    11 |
    12 |   useEffect(() => {
    13 |     fetchUsers()


ERROR in src/components/users/UserResults.tsx:10:17

TS2339: Property 'loading' does not exist on type '{}'.
     8 |
     9 | function UserResults() {
  > 10 |   const {users, loading, fetchUsers} = useContext(GithubContext)
       |                 ^^^^^^^
    11 |
    12 |   useEffect(() => {
    13 |     fetchUsers()


ERROR in src/components/users/UserResults.tsx:10:26

TS2339: Property 'fetchUsers' does not exist on type '{}'.
     8 |
     9 | function UserResults() {
  > 10 |   const {users, loading, fetchUsers} = useContext(GithubContext)
       |                          ^^^^^^^^^^
    11 |
    12 |   useEffect(() => {
    13 |     fetchUsers()


ERROR in src/components/users/UserResults.tsx:19:21

TS7006: Parameter 'user' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    17 |     return (
    18 |       <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-8 xl:grid-cols-4 lg:grid-cols-3 md:grid-cols-2">
  > 19 |         {users.map((user) => {
       |                     ^^^^
    20 |           return <UserItem key={user.id} userData={user} />;
    21 |         })}
    22 |       </div>
```

Comment: You need to pass a type parameter to `useContext`, otherwise it will infer the type of the empty object you passed in.

Comment: @JaredSmith You mean like useContext<any>(GithubContext)?
the error goes away but the app does not works, It says users does not exist and of course user neither.

Comment: Yes but don't use `any`, use the *actual* type of the thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not defining your types for your context. Fix would be like this

```
type GithubContextTypes = {
    users: User[];
    loading: boolean;
    fetchUsers: () => void;
}

const GithubContext = createContext({} as GithubContextTypes);
```

Comment: There's no need for a cast, createContext takes a type param.